# Unable to update Jenkins "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File parameter 'file is not writable: '/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/junit.jpi'"

Tags: jenkins, vagrant, centos7

I am unable to get Jenkins to update to a new version. It is currently running on CentOS 7. Followed the install instructions https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/ here hoping to upgrade it, and although it appears to be doing so, the moment I try to load into the server it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7ZNS.png). I've tried looking into this and have seen a similar error occur but it only happened in the plugins section, not the entire page.

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File parameter 'file is not writable: '/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/junit.jpi'
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.requireCanWrite(FileUtils.java:2619)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(FileUtils.java:2447)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(FileUtils.java:2415)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyToFile(FileUtils.java:1042)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:952)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(FileUtils.java:1069)
    at hudson.PluginManager.copyBundledPlugin(PluginManager.java:1057)
    at hudson.PluginManager.loadPluginsFromWar(PluginManager.java:649)
    at hudson.PluginManager.loadDetachedPlugins(PluginManager.java:747)
    at hudson.LocalPluginManager.loadBundledPlugins(LocalPluginManager.java:78)
    at hudson.PluginManager$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:405)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1158)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1191)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:989)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:297)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:314)
```

Comment: Ha e you checked the file permission? Is the user the Jenkins user? Is it and the directory writable?

Comment: How would I go about checking all those? I am very new to all of this. I have currently been logged in as root while updating. Not even sure how to create a Jenkins user.

Comment: Tried updating Jenkins with the .war file instead. Updated all the permissions and user but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the jenkins version, a lot of files ownership is changed from jenkins to your OS user.

The best solution is

```
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins
```

Comment: Did you try this solution? Did it work for you?